# Materialize CSS- Align navbar to the far right

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am using materialize CSS and have created a Nav but want to move it a bit further to the right without affecting the position of the logo. See current image below;

Navbar photo
[image: Navbar photo]

My current code:

```
< div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav class="white" role="navigation" id="top-nav">
    <div class="nav-wrapper container">
      <a id = "logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo"><img src = "img/DataNavSmaller.png" ></ a >

        < ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href = "#" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#" > Who We Are</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#" > What We Do</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#" > Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul id = "nav-mobile" class="sidenav">
        <li><a href = "#" > Navbar Link</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a href = "#" data-target="nav-mobile" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
nav.brand - logo {

    margin - left: -60px;
    padding - top: 4px;
}

nav.right {

    padding - top: 10px;

}
nav ul a{

    color: black;
    font - size:20px;

}
```

How can i achieve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the right of your navbar with CSS properties `position: fixed; top: 10px; right: 5px;`. `position: fixed` makes the element stay in place. `top` specifies the distance the element is from the `top` and `right` specifies the distance the element is from the `right` (these properties only work when the `display` property is set).

```css
.navbar-fixed{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #BEBEBE;
}
.logo{
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 15px;
   background: red;
   padding: 5px;
   background: linear-gradient(red, yellow, green);
   width: 60px;
   height: 25px;
   color: white;
}
.navbar-right{
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 5px;/*pixels away from the right of the navbar*/
}

.title{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-fixed">
<div class="logo">
<!--<img src="something.png" alt="img"/>-->
DataNav
</div>
<div class="navbar-right">
<div class="title">
Home
</div>
<div class="title">
Who we are
</div>
<div class="title">
What we do
</div>
<div class="title">
Contact us
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, the position:fixed changed the issue. Default position was absolute.

Comment: @Couch No problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about

> nav .right { 
>   float: right; 
>   }

Comment: The default property was float:right, changing the position from absolute to fixed sorted the issue out.